# Validator expression to compare the values of specific element of an array while inserting a document in MogoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to write a validator expression while inserting the document in a collection. For example , my collection contains data:

```
[
  {
    "username": u1,
    emails: [
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u1@email.com,
        primary: true
      },
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u1_1@email.com,
        primary: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": u2,
    emails: [
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u2@email.com,
        primary: true
      },
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u2_1@email.com,
        primary: false
      },
     {
        type: "work",
        value: u2_2@email.com,
        primary: false
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

While inserting new data , I want to validate that the primary email is not duplicate i.e. email mentioned in the object having “primary:true” should not contain in any document’s primary’s email. For example if I insert

```
{
    "username": u3,
    emails: [
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u2@email.com,
        primary: true
      },
      {
        type: "work",
        value: u2_1@email.com,
        primary: false
      }
    ]
  }
```

It shouldn’t allow me to insert as user U2 has same primary email. I am struggling with the creation of validator expression. I read about Unique index with partialFilterExpression but having difficulties with that expressions too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a multikey unique index like this:

```
db.coll.createIndex({"emails.value": 1, "emails.primary": 1}, {unique: true})
```

[Documentation link.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/)

Update create a combination of unique and partial filter expression like this:

```
db.coll.createIndex({'emails.value': 1, 'emails.primary': 1}, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { 'emails.primary': true }})
```

[Partial Indexes Documentation.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/)

Comment: Here I want to achieve uniqueness only for the elements where "primary:true". Same email value is allowed for elements where primary:false

Comment: I tried using partialFilterExpression but it doesn't work. It is checking uniqueness for the emails elements where "primary:false" too

Comment: I used the second query it worked as expected, what partial filter did you created?